# Why I cannot create directory in makefile?

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

```
ODIR =./obj

SRCS = myfunc.cpp
DEPS = header.h

OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRCS))
_OBJ = $(ODIR)/$(OBJ)

$(DLL): $(_OBJ)
    if test ! -d $(ODIR); then mkdir $(ODIR); fi
    $(AR) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ 

$(_OBJ): $(SRCS) $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(INCL) $(LDFLAGS)
```

I want to put all my object file in a directory `./obj`. I want to create it if such a directory is not existing. What is wrong with  `if test ! -d $(ODIR); then mkdir $(ODIR); fi`? The error said

> Assembler messages: Fatal error: can't create obj/: Is a directory

Comment: It looks like `$(OBJ)` is the empty string.

Comment: You don't need to test for existence of the directory, if you use `mkdir -p`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that `DLL` isn't defined anywhere.

The second problem is here:

```
OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRCS))
```

See the space after the first comma? It looks innocuous, but it means that the variable `OBJ` winds up containing  `myfunc.o`, which also looks harmless, until you construct `_OBJ` which turns out to be `./obj/ myfunc.o`, which trips up the compiler.

The third problem is that Make will execute the `$(_OBJ)` rule before the `$(DLL)` rule, so the compiler must use the `obj/` directory before it exists.

The last problem (I hope) is that you seem to be passing `$(CFLAGS)` as arguments to the archive-maintaining program, when you should use `$(ARFLAGS)` (and make sure it actually contains what you intend).

Comment: You are right. Need the move `if...` to the `$(_OBJ)` rule.

Answer (score 4):

A final problem that isn't a problem yet but will be:

```
SRCS = myfunc.cpp
OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCS))
_OBJ = $(ODIR)/$(OBJ)
```

As long as `SRCS` only contains one file, this will be fine.  But as soon as you add a second file, the above is wrong.

Suppose `SRCS` contains `myfunc.cpp myother.cpp`.  Then `OBJ` contains `myfunc.o myother.o`.  Then `_OBJ`, which is `$(ODIR)/$(OBJ)`, will be `./obj/myfunc.o myother.o` which is not what you want.

Better is to just write it as a single change:

```
SRCS = myfunc.cpp
_OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp,$(ODIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
```